# Getting service metadata of SAPUI5 v2 ODataModel?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I try to get the service metadata of a sapui5 v2 odata model.
Code:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(someServiceURL);
var oMetadata = oModel.getServiceMetadata();
```

This should work according to this page:
https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html

Anyhow I got "`undefined`" for `oMetadata`.
If I change code to:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel({
        loadMetadataAsync : false,
        serviceUrl : someServiceURL
});
```

Still `oMetadata === undefined`

According to SDK documentation metadata should be loaded in sync:

> Return the metadata object. Please note that when using the model with
>   bLoadMetadataAsync = true then this function might return undefined
>   because the metadata has not been loaded yet. In this case attach to
>   the metadataLoaded event to get notified when the metadata is
>   available and then call this function.

What is wrong with my code?

I am using (1.28.11):

```
<script src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"    ...
```

I started debugging the UI5 code and detected following line:
this.bLoadMetadataAsync = true;

I started debugging of SAPUI5 code and detected following line (seems to be called each time):

```
this.bLoadMetadataAsync = true;
```

Is it a bug? Or is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**
The following worked for me in an actual application environment. I guess it not being fired in my fiddle was due to no actual data request being made:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(<ServiceURL>);

oModel.attachMetadataLoaded(null, function(){
   var oMetadata = oModel.getServiceMetadata();
   console.log(oMetadata);
},null);
```

**Lead up to the solution:**

Ok so I started playing around with this a bit and found the following:

- `.getServiceMetadata()` worked fine with `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`.
- with the `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` the request for the metadata was sent through the network but somehow `.getServiceMetadata()` returned `undefined`.
- I tried to `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.attachMetadataLoaded()` but the event was never fired. (This only applied in the jsbin I used)

I will edit this with any further findings I make. If you have anything that should be included in my findings/testing just tell me.

**Edit:**

The `bLoadMetadataAsync` is a parameter you can set on the `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`. The parameter is not in the API for `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` anymore. I assume that the async loading has been choosen as default.

**Edit:**
@user3783327 Reported a bug here: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/564

Comment: Thanks, was a typo in the issue. Of course I used the same variable. I fixed the text.

Comment: Did some diging into this. Edited my answer.

Comment: Than the documentation is wrong or we detected a bug? Compare that page: https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html

Comment: There is no mention of the not async loading being available on the 'v2.OdataModel'.

Comment: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#getServiceMetadata says _Return the metadata object. Please note that when using the model with bLoadMetadataAsync = true then this function might return undefined because the metadata has not been loaded yet. In this case attach to the metadataLoaded event to get notified when the metadata is available and then call this function. _

Comment: Yes while this looks a lot like copy pasta it is not necessary false. It just fails to mention that (as you discovered) the `bLoadMetadataAsync` is always `true` for the `v2.ODataModel`. Lets see what the raised issue yields as a result.

Comment: The next version of UI5 will have a method on the model that returns a promise: https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#metadataLoaded

This makes it easier to use the completely asynchronous v2 model: oModel.metadataLoaded().then(function() { [...] });

Answer (score 0):

As [sirion already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938755/getting-service-metadata-of-sapui5-v2-odatamodel#comment51977525_31940797), the ODataModel has now an API named [`metadataLoaded`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/metadataLoaded) which returns a promise accordingly. In the resolve function, we can definitely get the service metadata [via `getServiceMetadata()`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/getServiceMetadata).

```js
myODataModel.metadataLoaded()
  .then(() =>/* Do something with */myODataModel.getServiceMetadata());
```

---

Alternatively, we can also make use of [ODataMetaModel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataMetaModel) which can be set on any ManagedObject (including View) and provides several useful accessors related to the service metadata. In order to get the meta model, we need to use the appropriate API from the ODataModel instead of instantiating the model directly:

```js
myODataModel.getMetaModel().loaded()
  .then(() =>/* Do something with */myODataModel.getMetaModel()/*...*/);
```

[Documentation: Meta Model for OData V2](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2#loio341823349ed04df1813197f2a0d71db2)