# How to get model on onInit?

Tags: odata, sapui5

In `manifest.json`, I have following model definition:

```json
{
    "sap.ui5": {
        "models": {
            "SalesInvoices": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
                "settings": {
                    "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
                    "defaultCountMode": "Request"
                },
                "dataSource": "ZAM_SALES_STATISTICS_CDS",
                "preload": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `SalesInvoices` is connected to the `OData` service.

Now on the `onInit` function in the controller, I am trying to get `Metadata` from `OData` as following:

```js
{ // Controller
    onInit: function() {
        const oPayerModel = this.getView().getModel("SalesInvoices");
        console.log(oPayerModel.getMetadata());
        setTimeout(() => {
            const oPayerModel = this.getView().getModel("SalesInvoices");
            console.log(oPayerModel.getMetadata());
        }, 600);
    },
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, I have to delay to get the OData instance.
`setTimeout` is not recommended to use in SAPUI5, how can I do it better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can **avoid `setTimeout`**, as [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47390884/5846045), by using the `v2.ODataModel` API [`metadataLoaded`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/metadataLoaded) instead which returns a promise. The promise is fulfilled once the service metadata is loaded successfully.

```js
onInit: async function() {
  const oPayerModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("SalesInvoices");
  try {
    await oPayerModel.metadataLoaded(true);
    const oServiceMetadata = oPayerModel.getServiceMetadata(); // NOT .getMetadata()
    // ...
  } catch (oError) {/* ... */}
},
```

---

About the model being undefined in `onInit`, here are answers with better explanations:

- [Nabi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48397461/5846045)
- [My other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251431/5846045)

Comment: The object `oPayerModel` is undefined on `const oPayerModel = this.getView().getModel("SalesInvoices");`, that why I use `setTimeout()`, because of the delay. Why `oPayerModel` is undefined?

Comment: @zero_coding So that's the actual problem. It would've been nice if you could've mentioned that in your question. Anyhow, my fault since I overlooked that. As [mentioned by Nabi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48397461/5846045) or [in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251431/5846045), replace `.getView().getModel` with `.getOwnerComponent().getModel`. The reason for that is that the view doesn't know its parent yet in `onInit`. So the model from the component (defined in manifest) isn't propagated to the view yet.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are running into the issue I reported some time ago: [Component + default OData model: this.getView().getModel() returns undefined in onInit() of controllers](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/790):

- **don't use** `this.getView().getModel()` directly in `onInit()`
- **instead use** `this.getOwnerComponent().getModel()` in `onInit()`
- **anywhere else** in the controller you can use `this.getView().getModel()`

In your case you should be fine changing the suggestion of @boghyon slightly:

```
onInit: function() {
  const oPayerModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("SalesInvoices");
  oPayerModel.metadataLoaded().then(this.onMetadataLoaded.bind(this, oPayerModel));
},

onMetadataLoaded: function(myODataModel) {
  const metadata = myODataModel.getServiceMetadata(); // NOT .getMetadata()
  // ...
},
```

This way you can get rid of `setTimeout(...)`.